# Login with Facebook same PHP login and callback

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have the following PHP script: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login it works fine but i dont want to separate login and callback to 2 different php file. I want to take the callback to the login.php what have I done? Is there any kind of `if(isset(?????))` command or something like that?

Comment: add some parameter in your callback URL and on the same page check that parameter.if found then callback will work, otherwise login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is at http://example.com/login.php, add something like http://example.com/login.php?fb_flag=response in the response URL and when this will be set, run response code else run login code.

Comment: You mean like if($_GET['fb_flag']=='response') {}

Comment: Yes.. In if write the code for response and in else write the code for login process

Comment: Yes there would not be any problem with that. Actually no one can edit the response URL usually. In case some one do, they would not get the expected result. But it would not affect your website. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use HybirdAuth

http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/

It makes your life easy.